# Symfony4 work with multiple entity Manager and connection

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working on an App which is built with Symfony and twig.App is connected to two database and have two entity manager as you can see in my configuration below.

When I try to used the default entity manager called (neobe) in my case on (APP\Entity\NeoBe) everything work good, but I can't use another entity manager (neobesante) on (APP\Entity\NeoBeSante)for processing data  from entity. Below is the snippet code:

Where am I wrong?

```
Doctrine.yaml config:

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: neobe
        connections:
            neobe:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_NEOBE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            neobesante:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_NEOBESANTE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ciController\PropertyController

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: neobe
        entity_managers:
            neobe:
                connection: neobe
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    NeoBe:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/NeoBe'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\NeoBe'
                        alias: NeoBe
            neobesante:
                connection: neobesante
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    NeoBeSante:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/NeoBeSante'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\NeoBeSante'
                        alias: NeoBeSante
```

Here is my controller:

```
       $customerNeoBeRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Customer::class,'neobe')->findOneBy(["email" => $userEmail]);
       $customerNeoBeSanteRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Customer::class,'neobesante')->findOneBy(["email" => $userEmail]);
```

Comment: The fact that getRepository only takes one argument implies your approach will not work.  Your prefixes are probably messed up as well.  Your best bet might be to define your repositories as services in which case they will pick the correct entity manager.  Search for ServiceEntityRepository for examples.

Comment: I figure out  the solution .Placing the 'default' entity manager last in doctrine.yaml got this to work as expected.